# Meteor.call and latency compensation

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to understand why am I getting the error when calling a meteor server method. It works on the server side but it's throwing errors in the browser.

This is my server code in **/server/methods.js** file:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getTicketSettings: function(){
        var getTicketConfig = function(callback){
            Assets.getText('ticketCustomizing.json', function(error, res){
                if (error)
                    throw new Meteor.Error({error:'ticket-getCustomizing', reason:'No se pudo recuperar la configuración.'});
                else callback && callback(null, JSON.parse(res));
            });
        }

        var syncAssetRetrieve = Meteor.wrapAsync(getTicketConfig);
        var result = syncAssetRetrieve();
        return result;
    },
});
```

And this is in my client/server code in **/lib/initialization.js** file:

```
App.config.tickets.tipos = new Mongo.Collection('tipos');

Meteor.startup(function(){
    moment.locale('es');

     var ticketSettingsObj = Meteor.call('getTicketSettings');
     console.log(ticketSettingsObj);

     _.map(ticketSettingsObj.tipos, function(tipo){
         App.config.tickets.tipos.insert(tipo);
     });
});
```

When I run my application I have the JSON object logged in the console but the browser is showing this error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tipos' of undefined* in my **/lib/initialization.js** here:

```
_.map(ticketSettingsObj.tipos, function(tipo){
         App.config.tickets.tipos.insert(tipo);
     });
```

Obviously I misunderstood something but still wondering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to the Meteor.call. The server can run it synchronously, blocking until it gets a return, but the client cannot so ticketSettingsObj will always be undefined.

See [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call)

Without error handling (and untested):

```
Meteor.call('getTicketSettings', function(error, result){
  console.log(result);
  _.map(result.tipos, function(tipo){
     App.config.tickets.tipos.insert(tipo);
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I didn't read this carefully enough: "On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method."

Answer (score 1):

Do a `console.log(App.config.tickets)` and see if it returns a valid object. If it doesn't then you have defined the object `App.config.tickets` only on server side. If this is intentional and you only want this to be accessible on server side then then add a `if(Meteor.isServer)` or move the definition it to a file inside `/server` directory.